# Integral of product of characteristic functions

Tags: integration, measure-theory, solution-verification

Let $(X, \mathcal{M},\mu), (Y,\mathcal{N},\nu)$ be measure spaces. Show for characteristic functions $\chi_A \in L^{+}(X),\chi_B \in L^{+}(Y)$, that $\chi_{A\times B} \in L^{+}(X \times Y)$ and $$\int\chi_{A\times B} d(\mu \times \nu)=\int\chi_A d\mu \int \chi_B d\nu$$

Attempt: By definition of the product measure, $\int \chi_{A \times B} d(\mu \times \nu)=\mu(A)\nu(B)=\int\chi_A d\mu \int \chi_B d\nu$. Since $\int \chi_Ad\mu<\infty$ and $\int \chi_B d\nu<\infty$, we see that $\int\chi_A d\mu \int \chi_B d\nu<\infty$ and $\chi_{A \times B} \in L^{+}(X \times Y)$. That is all that is needed to show. Is this correct? I am struggling with the product measure and am using this to try to prove Folland exercise 2.51(B) I need to know if I have started the problem correctly.

Comment: where are you getting $\int X_A \,d\mu < \infty$ from? What you wrote is true regardless of the measures of $A$ and $B$ by definition of the product measure as you said.

Comment: @Mason doesnt $\chi_A \in L^{+}(X) \implies \int \chi_A d\mu<\infty$? Or is that only for $L^1$?

Comment: $L^+(X)$ is the space of measurable functions $f \colon X \to [0, \infty]$. Every characteristic function of a measurable set is in $L^+(X)$. $L^+(X)$ is independent of the measure on $X$. $L^1(X, \mu)$ is the space of measurable functions $f \colon X \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $\lVert f \rVert_{L^1} < \infty$ identified a.e..

Comment: @Mason so how do I show $\chi_{A\times B} \in L^{+}(X \times Y)$?

Comment: @Mason Also, I made this problem up to help me prove something in Folland. This was not given to me by a professor, so the problem statement may be vague or have errors. If so I would appreciate it if you would let me know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to see from the definition of measurability that for any measurable space $(Z, F)$, $S \subset Z$, $\chi_S$ is measurable if and only if $S$ is measurable.

If $A \in \mathcal{M}$ and $B \in \mathcal{N}$, then by definition of product measure, $A \times B \in \mathcal{M} \otimes \mathcal{N}$. Hence $\chi_{A \times B}$ is measurable.